# How would you implement lodash set method in Swift?

Tags: swift, lodash

Trying to figure out how to get a working iteration of lodash set method in Swift and can't seem to figure out how to do it.

> // Requiring the lodash library
> const _ = require("lodash");

> // The source object
> var obj = { 'cpp': [{ 'java': { 'python': 2012 } }] };

> // set the value by _.set() method
> _.set(obj, 'cpp[0].java.python', 2020);

> // return the new set object
> console.log(obj.cpp[0].java.python);

> // The source object
> result -> { 'cpp': [{ 'java': { 'python': 2020 } }] };

Paths are separated by a dot/period aka "a.b" and arrays are indicated by square brackets with the index in between like "a.b[0]". If the path is not found in the original dictionary it must be created.

Example 1:

`var currentDictionary = [String:Any]()`

`var result = currentDictionary.lodashSet("a.b", value: 1)`

`result = [ a : [ b : 1]]`

Example 2

`var currentDictionary = [a : b: [[c:0]]]`

`var result = currentDictionary.lodashSet("a.b[1].c", value: 1)`

`result = [a : b: [[c:0], [c:1]]]`

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lodash-_-set-method/

swift impl of lodash but without `setMethod`
https://github.com/ankurp/Dollar

Comment: It looks like lodash is a Javascript library? What does that have to do with Swift? You're going to have to provide more background on what you're trying to do. A Swift audience is unlikely to know anything about lodash.

Comment: We wouldn't implement it. Methods of this kind are essentially type-unsafe which goes directly against strong type safety of Swift.

Answer (score 0):

```
GraphQLMap is [String:Any]
```

```
    private enum PathType {
        case normal(path: String)
        case array(index: Int, path: String)
        case last(path: String)
    }

    private func castedPath(_ path: String) -> [PathType] {
        let paths = path.components(separatedBy: ".")
        var newArray = [PathType]()
        paths.enumerated().forEach { pathIndex, path in
            if let (path, index) = path.getArrayPathAndIndex(), let intValue = Int(index) {
                newArray.append(.array(index: intValue, path: path))
            } else if pathIndex == (paths.count - 1) {
                newArray.append(.last(path: path))
            } else {
                newArray.append(.normal(path: path))
            }
        }
        return newArray
    }
    
    func lodash_set(path: String, value: JSONEncodable) -> GraphQLMap {
        var castPath = castedPath(path)
        var accumulatedMap = GraphQLMap()
        let returnMap = setMap(originalMap: self, accumulatedMap: &accumulatedMap, paths: &castPath, value: value)
        
        return returnMap
    }
    
    private func setMap(originalMap: GraphQLMap?, accumulatedMap: inout GraphQLMap, paths: inout [PathType], value: JSONEncodable) -> GraphQLMap {
        let path = paths.removeFirst()
        
        switch path {
        case .normal(let path):
            if var hasValue = originalMap?[path] as? GraphQLMap {
                accumulatedMap[path] = setMap(originalMap: hasValue, accumulatedMap: &hasValue, paths: &paths, value: value)
            } else {
                var newMap = GraphQLMap()
                accumulatedMap[path] = setMap(originalMap: nil, accumulatedMap: &newMap, paths: &paths, value: value)
            }
        case .array(index: let index, path: let path):
            if var hasValue = originalMap?[path] as? [GraphQLMap] {
                if (hasValue.count - 1) >= index {
                    hasValue[index] = setMap(originalMap: hasValue[index], accumulatedMap: &hasValue[index], paths: &paths, value: value)
                    accumulatedMap[path] = hasValue
                } else {
                    var newMap = GraphQLMap()
                    hasValue.append(setMap(originalMap: nil, accumulatedMap: &newMap, paths: &paths, value: value))
                    accumulatedMap[path] = hasValue
                }
            } else {
                var newValue = GraphQLMap()
                let newArray = [setMap(originalMap: nil, accumulatedMap: &newValue, paths: &paths, value: value)]
                accumulatedMap[path] = newArray
            }
        case .last(let path):
            accumulatedMap[path] = value
            return accumulatedMap
        }
        
        return accumulatedMap
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).